# need to get array of values and compare in ts

Tags: typescript

**here i get one value and i compared ... but i need  to get array value and then process**
*find it*

```js
import { compile } from '../../src/index';
 
let customHelper: Object = {
  upperCase: (str: string) => {
    return str.toUpperCase();
  }
};
 
let data: object = { value: 20 };
 
let getDOMString: (data: object) => HTMLCollection = compile(
  '<div>' +
  '${if(value >= 10)}' +
  '<span> Value > Than 10 </span>' +
  '${else if(value === 10)}' +
  '<span> Value EqualTo 10 </span>' +
  '${else}' +
  '<span> Value < 10 </span>' +
  '${/if}' +
  '</div>',
  customHelper);
 
let opElem: HTMLCollection = getDOMString(data);
 
document.getElementById('element').appendChild(opElem[0]);
```

*need to get array of values and compare*

Comment: here let  opelm get data value but i need to cange array value one by oone